# iphone:UItableviewcell reloads when scrolled

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

When I scroll my tableview,the whole data in each cell reloads.It doesn't show any problem in tablecell's view.
But it causes issues in calculating the total from the quantities retrieved from each cell.The total value re-adds when we scroll the tableview.

this is my code:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];   //subtitle view supprot

    }

    //Get the object from the array.
    order *orderObj = [appDelegate.orderArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //Set the ordername.
    cell.textLabel.text = orderObj.itemName;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Quantity : %@  Price : %@ Spiciness : %@", orderObj.quantity,orderObj.price,orderObj.spiciness];

       quan=[orderObj.quantity intValue];
       pri=[orderObj.price floatValue];

   [self calculateValues]; 

    return cell;

}
```

In calculate values :

```
-(void)calculateValues{

    itemPrice=itemPrice+pri;

    float subtot=quan * itemPrice;

    _subTotal.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", subtot];


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take a variable in .h file say mLastIndex and set it's initial value to -1

```
mLastIndex = -1;
```

and then change in your cellForRowAtIndexPath as

```
if (indexPath.row > mLastIndex) {
            [self calculateValues]; 
            mLastIndex = indexPath.row;
        }
```

Comment: Why dont you calculate the subtotal in method cellforrowatindexpath means where your diplaying cell.textlable and detail lable,and add one more custom label and show the calculated subtotal

Comment: @Inder Kumar Rathore Thanks for your reply.Now I got only the last cell's quantity and price.How could get the total of all cell items?

Comment: just debug it... the above method will be called for new added rows... as you can see for all indexpath.row >  mLastIndex;

Comment: @Inder Kumar Rathore Now the calculations are correct.When there are more items the total becomes correct only when scrolled completely.ie total only calculates when we access it by scrolling

Comment: if you want to show total of all objects the why are you putting all this in cell for row, put a for loop in view did load and calculate all the values there